# Prove that $\lim _{x\rightarrow1}\frac {1-x}{1-x^{2}}=\frac {1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

- Prove that $\lim _{x\rightarrow1}\dfrac {1-x}{1-x^{2}}=\dfrac {1}{2}$

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Pick $\delta=\min \left\{ 1,\varepsilon\right\}$.

Then, if $\left| x-1\right|<\delta$ then $\left| \dfrac {1-x}{1-x^{2}}-\dfrac {1}{2}\right|=\dfrac {\left| 1-x\right| }{2\left| 1+x\right| }<\dfrac {\delta}{6}<\delta\leq \varepsilon$.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: It is the right idea, where do you get $6$ in in the denominator?  I have $\delta < 1 \implies x+1 > 1$ and $|\frac {1-x}{2(1+x)}| < \frac {\delta}{2}$

Comment: @DougM If $0<\left| x-1\right| <\delta$ then, we obtain $2<1+x<\delta +2$. So, $\left| 1+x\right|$ is bounded by $3$. Hence, $\dfrac {1}{\left| 1+x\right| }<1/3$, right?

Comment: @DougM Upss... My idea is false.

Comment: $|x-1| < \delta \implies  -\delta < x-1 < \delta \implies 2-\delta < x + 1$ and if $\delta < 1, x+1 > 1$

Answer (score 0):

If we say $f(x) = \frac{1 - x}{1 - x^2} = \frac{1 - x}{(1 + x)(1 - x)} = \frac{1}{1 + x}$

then $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + 1} = \frac{1}{2}$

And that'd be a "reproof" of your proof, right?

EDT: What I meant to say was that I showed that the outcome of your proof is correct, and that I can't seem to find any mistakes in the route you picked, so I guess you're entirely right!